# mysql copy and insert rows in same table with new primary key and sequence number

Tags: mysql

I have multiple table with primary key, data columns and batch no.

I require procedure which dynamically creates statement to copy rows from table and insert into same table by changing auto increment value batch no.

**Original Table**

[image]

mysql query should copy records of batch 1 and paste them as batch 10 as below

[image]

I have tried to write query but it is coping all records, also it gets failed timeout for large no of records.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `duplicateRows`(_schemaName text, _tableName text, _omitColumns text, var_run_seq_no int,var_old_run_seq_no int)
    BEGIN
SELECT IF(TRIM(_omitColumns) <> '', CONCAT('id', ',', TRIM(_omitColumns),'batch_no'), CONCAT('id',',batch_no')) INTO @omitColumns;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE 
table_schema = _schemaName 
AND 
table_name = _tableName 
AND 
FIND_IN_SET(COLUMN_NAME,@omitColumns) = 0 
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION INTO @columns;

SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', _tableName, '(', @columns, ',batch_no)',
  'SELECT ', @columns, ',', var_batch_no,
  ' FROM ', _schemaName, '.', _tableName);

-- select @sql;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
END
```

Comment: Don't include `id` in the list.

Comment: @Rick cound,t get you, can you explain in details

Comment: If you want `AUTO_INCREMENT` to create new ids, don't specify it when inserting.

Comment: What is `var_batch_no` and how is it populated/set? Where is the `WHERE` clause that designates the rows to be copied (`WHERE batch_no = 1` in this case)?  I suggest you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the following table, containing test data as specified in your question.  Notice that the id column is "AUTO_INCREMENTed". (MySQL version 5.7)

```
create table batches (
  id int auto_increment primary key
, first_name varchar(32)
, last_name varchar(32)
, address varchar(32)
, batch_no integer
);

insert into batches (first_name, last_name, address, batch_no) values
 ('william','Faulkner','UK',1), ('suzy','nicholus','US',1)
,('ganesh','bora','india',1), ('mahadev','patil','india',1)
,('prasad','k','UK',2), ('sandeep','g','US',2)
,('prajakta','J','india',2), ('Nimish','G','india',2);

select * from batches;
+----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| id | first_name | last_name | address | batch_no |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+
|  1 | william    | Faulkner  | UK      |        1 |
|  2 | suzy       | nicholus  | US      |        1 |
|  3 | ganesh     | bora      | india   |        1 |
|  4 | mahadev    | patil     | india   |        1 |
|  5 | prasad     | k         | UK      |        2 |
|  6 | sandeep    | g         | US      |        2 |
|  7 | prajakta   | J         | india   |        2 |
|  8 | Nimish     | G         | india   |        2 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

The following procedure may help you to find a solution that fits your purpose.  Your initial idea - assembling a combination of an INSERT and a SELECT, and executing it - is still in there, just the method of finding all necessary columns is different.

```
delimiter //

create procedure duplicate_rows (
  schema_ text
, table_ text
, oldbatch_ int
, newbatch_ int)
begin

  declare colINSERT_ text default '' ; -- columns needed for INSERTing
  declare colSELECT_ text default '' ; -- columns needed for SELECTing
-- Find all columns for INSERT and SELECT, respectively. () contain "insert" cols.
-- Exclude the 'id' and 'batch_no' columns from the column list(s).
  select 
      concat( '(', group_concat(column_name), ',batch_no)') 
    , concat( group_concat(column_name), ',', newbatch_ )
    into colINSERT_, colSELECT_ 
    from information_schema.columns 
   where table_schema = schema_
     and table_name = table_
     and column_name not in ('id', 'batch_no'); 

  set @sql = concat(
    'insert into '       , table_, colINSERT_
  , ' select '           , colSELECT_ 
  , ' from '             , table_
  , ' where batch_no = ' , oldbatch_
  );

  prepare stmt_ from @sql;
  execute stmt_;
  set @sql = '';

end//

delimiter ;
```

Test

```
mysql> call duplicate_rows('test', 'batches', 1, 20);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from batches;
+----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| id | first_name | last_name | address | batch_no |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+
|  1 | william    | Faulkner  | UK      |        1 |
|  2 | suzy       | nicholus  | US      |        1 |
|  3 | ganesh     | bora      | india   |        1 |
|  4 | mahadev    | patil     | india   |        1 |
|  5 | prasad     | k         | UK      |        2 |
|  6 | sandeep    | g         | US      |        2 |
|  7 | prajakta   | J         | india   |        2 |
|  8 | Nimish     | G         | india   |        2 |
|  9 | william    | Faulkner  | UK      |       20 |
| 10 | suzy       | nicholus  | US      |       20 |
| 11 | ganesh     | bora      | india   |       20 |
| 12 | mahadev    | patil     | india   |       20 |
+----+------------+-----------+---------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice: when using this procedure, you may encounter "gaps" in auto-incremented ID columns.  More information about this:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315012/what-if-auto-increment-gaps-caused-by-mysql-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841104/how-to-fill-in-the-holes-in-auto-incremenet-fields

Answer (score 1):

I am proposing a new design that will normalize the customers in each batch

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ganeshbora;
CREATE DATABASE ganeshbora;
USE ganeshbora
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(20),
    lastname  VARCHAR(20),
    address   VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE batch_sequence
(
    batch_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE batches
(
    batch_id INT NOT NULL,
    cust_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_id,cust_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (cust_id,batch_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Let's create the `customer`, `batch_sequence` and `batches` tables

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ganeshbora;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.40 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE ganeshbora;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> USE ganeshbora
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE customer
    -> (
    ->     cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     firstname VARCHAR(20),
    ->     lastname  VARCHAR(20),
    ->     address   VARCHAR(40),
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE batch_sequence
    -> (
    ->     batch_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (batch_id)
    -> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE batches
    -> (
    ->     batch_id INT NOT NULL,
    ->     cust_id INT NOT NULL,
    ->     PRIMARY KEY (batch_id,cust_id),
    ->     UNIQUE KEY (cust_id,batch_id)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.36 sec)
```

Let's load  the `customer` table

```
mysql> INSERT INTO customer (firstname,lastname,address) VALUES
    -> ('william','Faulkner','UK'), ('suzy','nicholus','US'),
    -> ('ganesh','bora','india'), ('mahadev','patil','india'),
    -> ('prasad','k','UK'), ('sandeep','g','US'),
    -> ('prajakta','J','india'), ('Nimish','G','india');
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 8  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Let's load the first batch

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.15 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id) VALUES
    -> (@next_batch_id,1),(@next_batch_id,2),(@next_batch_id,3),(@next_batch_id,4);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Let's load the second batch

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id) VALUES
    -> (@next_batch_id,5),(@next_batch_id,6),(@next_batch_id,7),(@next_batch_id,8);
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Let's see what these table contain

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM customer;
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
| cust_id | firstname | lastname | address |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
|       1 | william   | Faulkner | UK      |
|       2 | suzy      | nicholus | US      |
|       3 | ganesh    | bora     | india   |
|       4 | mahadev   | patil    | india   |
|       5 | prasad    | k        | UK      |
|       6 | sandeep   | g        | US      |
|       7 | prajakta  | J        | india   |
|       8 | Nimish    | G        | india   |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM batches;
+----------+---------+
| batch_id | cust_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        1 |       2 |
|        1 |       3 |
|        1 |       4 |
|        2 |       5 |
|        2 |       6 |
|        2 |       7 |
|        2 |       8 |
+----------+---------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let's join them to produce your desired output

```
mysql> SELECT B.*,A.batch_id FROM batches A INNER JOIN customer B USING (cust_id);
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
| cust_id | firstname | lastname | address | batch_id |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
|       1 | william   | Faulkner | UK      |        1 |
|       2 | suzy      | nicholus | US      |        1 |
|       3 | ganesh    | bora     | india   |        1 |
|       4 | mahadev   | patil    | india   |        1 |
|       5 | prasad    | k        | UK      |        2 |
|       6 | sandeep   | g        | US      |        2 |
|       7 | prajakta  | J        | india   |        2 |
|       8 | Nimish    | G        | india   |        2 |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let's copy batch 1 into a new batch

```
mysql> LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.12 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UNLOCK TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id)
    -> SELECT @next_batch_id,cust_id FROM batches WHERE batch_id = 1;
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Let's join them again to produce your desired output

```
mysql> SELECT B.*,A.batch_id FROM batches A INNER JOIN customer B USING (cust_id);
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
| cust_id | firstname | lastname | address | batch_id |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
|       1 | william   | Faulkner | UK      |        1 |
|       2 | suzy      | nicholus | US      |        1 |
|       3 | ganesh    | bora     | india   |        1 |
|       4 | mahadev   | patil    | india   |        1 |
|       5 | prasad    | k        | UK      |        2 |
|       6 | sandeep   | g        | US      |        2 |
|       7 | prajakta  | J        | india   |        2 |
|       8 | Nimish    | G        | india   |        2 |
|       1 | william   | Faulkner | UK      |        3 |
|       2 | suzy      | nicholus | US      |        3 |
|       3 | ganesh    | bora     | india   |        3 |
|       4 | mahadev   | patil    | india   |        3 |
+---------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

The only thing my answer does differently from what you want is generate batch numbers sequentially by 1.

Please note that I made the a third table called `batch_sequence`. The purpose of this table is just to generate batch ids. I treat the `batch_sequence`
table like and Oracle or PostgreSQL Sequence Object. I prefer making this table MyISAM to ensure a full table lock when creating a new sequence number.

Please also note that [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) is used to retrieve whatever the next sequence number is after an `INSERT` into the `batch_sequence` table.

#### What are the Advantages ?

- You do not need to duplicate names and addresses
- Represent batches with smaller amount of data
- Guarantee uniqueness of batch ids by serialization
- Multiple processes can add batches without batch_id collision

#### Conclusion

If you decide to go with this, the stored procedure should be using this

```
LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
UNLOCK TABLES;
INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id)
SELECT @next_batch_id,cust_id FROM batches WHERE batch_id = (whatever batch id);
```

If you want to cut-and-paste all the sample code above, here it is

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ganeshbora;
CREATE DATABASE ganeshbora;
USE ganeshbora
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    cust_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    firstname VARCHAR(20),
    lastname  VARCHAR(20),
    address   VARCHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (cust_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE batch_sequence
(
    batch_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
CREATE TABLE batches
(
    batch_id INT NOT NULL,
    cust_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (batch_id,cust_id),
    UNIQUE KEY (cust_id,batch_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO customer (firstname,lastname,address) VALUES
('william','Faulkner','UK'), ('suzy','nicholus','US'),
('ganesh','bora','india'), ('mahadev','patil','india'),
('prasad','k','UK'), ('sandeep','g','US'),
('prajakta','J','india'), ('Nimish','G','india');
LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
UNLOCK TABLES;
INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id) VALUES
(@next_batch_id,1),(@next_batch_id,2),(@next_batch_id,3),(@next_batch_id,4);
LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
UNLOCK TABLES;
INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id) VALUES
(@next_batch_id,5),(@next_batch_id,6),(@next_batch_id,7),(@next_batch_id,8);
SELECT * FROM customer;
SELECT * FROM batches;
SELECT B.*,A.batch_id FROM batches A INNER JOIN customer B USING (cust_id);
LOCK TABLES batch_sequence WRITE;
INSERT INTO batch_sequence VALUES ();
SET @next_batch_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
ALTER TABLE batch_sequence ENGINE=MyISAM;
UNLOCK TABLES;
INSERT INTO batches (batch_id,cust_id)
SELECT @next_batch_id,cust_id FROM batches WHERE batch_id = 1;
SELECT B.*,A.batch_id FROM batches A INNER JOIN customer B USING (cust_id);
```